The independence of Lagrangian on the derivative
In this 2007 note by Mark Alford, the author said:

The analysis of field transformations that is traditionally presented in textbooks (e.g. Srednicki, “Quantum Field Theory”, Sec. 22) has two significant limitations:


i) It only applies to field theories whose Lagrange density $L(ϕ, ∂_μϕ)$ is just a function of the field $ϕ$ and its first derivative $∂_μϕ$: the proof fails if higher derivatives are present.
ii) It cannot be applied to field theories that are regulated by formulating them on a spacetime lattice.



My main question is about the second limitation if I can get this one about the first limitation answered.
So the author says:

in those theories, a derivative is discretized to something like $(ϕ(z + a)−ϕ(z − a))/2a$,


So we're looking at null coordinates, right?

Is this a Wick rotation? It looks like it fits the definition.

$z$ is Euclidean time, right?


I'm not trying to get an extra 3 wishes from the genie, I'm stating my present understanding, to give context.
A is the spatial displacement during the interval of this Lagrangian. I hope.

the action is a function of the field values $ϕ(x)$ at lattice sites, and $L(x)$ just depends on $ϕ(x)$.  In the continuum limit, where the lattice spacing goes to zero, this is still true, and there is never any separate dependence of $L(x)$ on $∂_μϕ$.

MY QUESTION IS:
Why is the independence of Lagrangian on the derivative important?

...context of mass as momentum in the direction of +time. can you clarify this? "mass as momentum" doesn't make sense to me, regardless of the "direction of time" part.

@KyleKanos This question represents my current location in the rabbit hole that began with my attempt to apply noethers theorem and group action on objects with mass. However, I removed that unnecessary personal commentary. If you still don't like it, tell me about it here instead of the comments: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/156668/the-cave-of-understanding

So we're looking at null coordinates, right? No. $z$ is Euclidean time, right? No.


For what it's worth, Alford is not considering a Wick rotation. Instead in (ii) he is analyzing possible extensions of Noether's theorem to continuum field theories regularized on a discretized spacetime lattice, where spacetime derivatives are replaced by finite differences; concretely he's displaying a central difference.

As to why ${\cal L}$'s dependence on the spacetime derivative $\partial_{\mu}\phi$ is important to the standard Noether's theorem for the continuum theory, one answer is that it is used in the formula for the Noether current.



Okay, that helps! Is that the same function that allows you to extract the stereo channels from a real function? == Also, if it's not Wick rotation, then is it still complex rotation?

@MissUnderstands where do you see a rotation in the document?

@MissUnderstands I am being nothing but polite here in an attempt to help you. The rotations you speak of involve multiplication of a real value by a complex value & I don't see such a multiplication in the document, so I'm curious as to where it is you are seeing that.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
